# java instantiate class without writing a constructor

Tags: java

whan I write a class like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public void print(){
    system.out.println("Hi")
   }
}
```

I can instantiate the class in the main even though It has no constructor written by me, is that because it inherits from Object anyway 
    ?

Comment: it is because when no constructor is provided in the class a default no parameter constructor is added, see [JLS 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited. But if no constructor is explicitly declared, the java compiler implicitly adds a default constructor.

See the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> **8.8.9. Default Constructor**
>
> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor is implicitly declared.